# Is it possible to teleport an entity to a nearby entity?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

With players, you can teleport *player1* to the closest nearby player with:

> /execute at *player1* run tp @p

But can the same be done with an entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To teleport an entity (such as an entity tagged `cow1`, for example), to the nearest entity that is not itself, use this command:

```
tp @s @e[tag=!cow1,sort=nearest,limit=1]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I suggest reading [this](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13507/what-to-do-before-asking-a-minecraft-commands-question) post's answer because it will likely have a lot of information which is helpful to you.

Secondly, *in it's simplest form* the `/tp` command takes two entity arguments, or one entity and one location argument. `/tp <entity> <entity>` or `/tp <entity> [<Pos>]`.

If you wanted to teleport the nearest sheep to the nearest villager, relative to your location, you would do `/tp @e[type=sheep,sort=nearest,limit=1] @e[type=villager,sort=nearest,limit=1]`.

**All entities selected by the first argument will be teleported to the entity selected by the second argument.** Keep in mind that the second selector *must* only select one entity, or otherwise you will get an error.

For more information, see the links provided in Robbie's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use @e to target all entities so if you wanted to teleport all cows near by you would use

```
/tp @e[type=cow]
```

to teleport the cows to the nearest player it would be

```
/tp @e[type=cow] @p
```

I don't believe there is a way to teleport a single entity.

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/teleport

https://minecraft.wiki/w/Target_selector